# How do I work with Javascript Object Literals in Python

Tags: javascript, python, json, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Through Beautifulsoup module I have extracted an HTML page. From that page, I further extracted a Javascript script tag. Inside the script tag, there is an object literal that I would like to work with. You can see what I would like to achieve:

```
<script>
            var main_obj = {

            "link":"",
            "stock":"",
            "price":[{"qty":1000,"value":"100$"}, {"qty":10000,"value":"1000$"}]

           } 

</script>
```

I would like to access the qty and value variables inside the object literals of price variable which is inside main_obj. Thankyou

Comment: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/gson-jsonparser.html

Comment: I need it in python.

Comment: Same idea...just `import json` and use `json.loads(json_string)`...http://developer.rhino3d.com/guides/rhinopython/python-xml-json/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use [`selenium`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html). In particular, you can use [`execute_script`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_script) to convert to a JSON string which Python can easily parse.

Since I don't know what the URL of the page you are working with is, I just created a local HTML file which included your script tag example. Using headless is not mandatory and I only added that option so the browser window doesn't open.

#### `test.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
    var main_obj = {
        "link": "",
        "stock": "",
        "price": [{"qty": 1000, "value": "100$"}, {"qty": 10000, "value": "1000$"}]
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Script

```
In[2]: import os
  ...: import json
  ...: 
  ...: from selenium import webdriver
  ...: 
  ...: chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  ...: chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
  ...: driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
  ...: 
  ...: driver.get('file://{}/test.html'.format(os.getcwd()))
  ...: json_string = driver.execute_script('return JSON.stringify(main_obj)')
  ...: driver.quit()
  ...: 
  ...: json_data = json.loads(json_string)
In[3]: json_data
Out[3]: 
{'link': '',
 'stock': '',
 'price': [{'qty': 1000, 'value': '100$'}, {'qty': 10000, 'value': '1000$'}]}
In[4]: for item in json_data['price']:
  ...:     print('Quantity: {:d}\tValue: ${:.2f}'.format(
  ...:         item['qty'], float(item['value'].rstrip('$'))
  ...:     ))
  ...: 
Quantity: 1000  Value: $100.00
Quantity: 10000 Value: $1000.00
```