# Unique string to Python Dictonary and then dump as yaml

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, yaml

1. The following output string is from a specific program and gets dumped in a text file. This more or less looks like python dictionary but isn't. [BTW. this is just a basic example but it might complex with multi layer dict]

   ```
   p_d: '{a:3, what:3.6864e-05, s:"lion", sst:'{c:-20, b:6, p:"panther"}}
   ```
2. First I wanted to convert this string output to a python dictionary format, so that I can then dump it into an yaml output file.
3. Tried like ast.literal_eval or json.loads or yaml.load, but wasn't successful. Wondering if there is any better custom way to convert this to python dictionary.

Update:

1. Tried the scenario which @Anthon provide and worked fine for one of the case scenarios. Thanks a lot for that.
2. And when tried with slightly complex scenario, faced the error.

   ```
   import sys
   import json
   import ruamel.yaml

   #Case 1
   #dit = "{p_d: '{a:3, what:3.6864e-05, s:lion, sst:'{c:-20, b:6, p:panther}}}"

   #Case 2
   dit = "'{p_d: '{a:3, what:3.6864e-05, s:lion, vec_mode:'{2.5, -2.9, 3.4, 5.6, -8.9, -5.67, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5.4, 2, 2, 6.545, 2, 2}, sst:'{c:-20, b:6, p:panther}}}"
   print(dit)

   yaml_str = dit.replace('"', '').replace("'",'').replace(':', ': ')
   print(yaml_str)


   print('#### full block style')
   yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe') # 
   yaml.default_flow_style = False
   data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
   yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)

   Output:
   '{p_d: '{a:3, what:3.6864e-05, s:lion, vec_mode:'{2.5, -2.9, 3.4, 5.6, -8.9, -5.67, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5.4, 2, 2, 6.545, 2, 2}, sst:'{c:-20, b:6, p:panther}}}
   {p_d:  {a: 3, what: 3.6864e-05, s: lion, vec_mode: {2.5, -2.9, 3.4, 5.6, -8.9, -5.67, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5.4, 2, 2, 6.545, 2, 2}, sst: {c: -20, b: 6, p: panther}}}
   #### full block style
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "./ditoyaml_ruamel.py", line 24, in <module>
   data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
   File "python3.6/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/main.py", line 434, in load
   return constructor.get_single_data()
   File "python3.6/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/constructor.py",     line 122, in get_single_data
   return self.construct_document(node)
   File "python3.6/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/constructor.py", line 132, in construct_document
   for _dummy in generator:
   File "python3.6/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/constructor.py", line 722, in construct_yaml_map
   value = self.construct_mapping(node)
   File "python3.6/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/constructor.py", line 446, in construct_mapping
   return BaseConstructor.construct_mapping(self, node, deep=deep)
   File "python3.6/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/constructor.py", line 264, in construct_mapping
   if self.check_mapping_key(node, key_node, mapping, key, value):
   File "python3.6/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/constructor.py", line 295, in check_mapping_key
   raise DuplicateKeyError(*args)
   ruamel.yaml.constructor.DuplicateKeyError: while constructing a mapping
   in "<unicode string>", line 1, column 52
   found duplicate key "2" with value "None" (original value: "None")
   in "<unicode string>", line 1, column 90

   To suppress this check see:
   http://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#duplicate-keys
   ```

Update:

1. Tried to suppress the error as suggested in the link with below code

   ```
   yaml.allow_duplicate_keys = True
   ```

Output:

```
'{p_d: '{a:3, what:3.6864e-05, s:lion, vec_mode:'{2.5, -2.9, 3.4, 5.6, -8.9, -5.67, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5.4, 2, 2, 6.545, 2, 2}, sst:'{c:-20, b:6, p:panther}}}
{p_d:  {a: 3, what: 3.6864e-05, s: lion, vec_mode: {2.5, -2.9, 3.4, 5.6, -8.9, -5.67, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5.4, 2, 2, 6.545, 2, 2}, sst: {c: -20, b: 6, p: panther}}}
#### full block style
p_d:
  a: 3
  s: lion
  sst:
    b: 6
    c: -20
    p: panther
  vec_mode:
    -8.9: null
    -5.67: null
    -2.9: null
    2: null
    2.5: null
    3.4: null
    5.4: null
    5.6: null
    6.545: null
  what: 3.6864e-05
```

It was add :null pair to it, but was expecting more like arrays. Something like as shown below. Trying further at my end.

```
'{p_d: '{a:3, what:3.6864e-05, s:lion, vec_mode:'{2.5, -2.9, 3.4, 5.6, -8.9, -5.67, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5.4, 2, 2, 6.545, 2, 2}, sst:'{c:-20, b:6, p:panther}}}
{p_d:  {a: 3, what: 3.6864e-05, s: lion, vec_mode: {2.5, -2.9, 3.4, 5.6, -8.9, -5.67, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5.4, 2, 2, 6.545, 2, 2}, sst: {c: -20, b: 6, p: panther}}}
#### full block style
p_d:
  a: 3
  s: lion
  sst:
    b: 6
    c: -20
    p: panther
  vec_mode:
    [-8.9,
    -5.67,
    -2.9,
    2,
    2.5,
    3.4,
    5.4,
    5.6,
    6.545]
  what: 3.6864e-05
```

Comment: As it's a nonstandard notation (lacking quotes around keys, etc), you'll need to write your own parser (far beyond the scope of a SO question). Or somehow force the culript program to use a recognised notation. *(Also, your sample has open single quotes without closing single quotes. So, that sample appears to be corrupt/incomplete/malformed.)*

Comment: That looks like JavaScript object literal syntax, but I'm not sure how that helps.

Comment: A brute force approach could be to embed the text as javascript in a basic html "file" and use a tool to scrape the JSON representation back out; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50709402/how-do-i-work-with-javascript-object-literals-in-pythonhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/50709402/how-do-i-work-with-javascript-object-literals-in-python

Comment: 1. Wondering how to put double quotes for all the variabels/elements. If that is done,
2. THen can use json.loads to put in dictionary format.
3. And then use yaml.dump to convert that dictionary format to yaml output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second single quote is very strangely placed, making the curly braces before and after it unbalanced.
So this is not a case of loading as-if YAML and then parsing (recursively) the values that look like a mapping/sequence.

On the other hand YAML doesn't need quoting unless the scalars start with, or in some cases contain, special
characters (e.g. `!` - tag, `:`+space - value indicator, `&` - anchor, etc.). And your input
doesn't seem to have that. So you can try to remove all quotes and make sure a space follows the value indicator (
necessary in YAML unless both key and value are quoted):

```py
import sys
import json
import ruamel.yaml

input_str = """\
p_d: '{a:3, what:3.6864e-05, s:"lion", sst:'{c:-20, b:6, p:"panther"}}
"""
    
yaml_str = input_str.replace('"', '').replace("'", '').replace(':', ': ')

print('#### preserved flow/block style')
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
print('#### flow/block style not preserved, with leaf-nodes in flow style')
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe') # doesn't preserve the flow/block style
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
print('#### full block style')
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe') # 
yaml.default_flow_style = False
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
print('#### json output, all quoted')
json.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
#### preserved flow/block style
p_d: {a: 3, what: 3.6864e-05, s: lion, sst: {c: -20, b: 6, p: panther}}
#### flow/block style not preserved, with leaf-nodes in flow style
p_d:
  a: 3
  s: lion
  sst: {b: 6, c: -20, p: panther}
  what: 3.6864e-05
#### full block style
p_d:
  a: 3
  s: lion
  sst:
    b: 6
    c: -20
    p: panther
  what: 3.6864e-05
#### json output, all quoted
{"p_d": {"a": 3, "what": 3.6864e-05, "s": "lion", "sst": {"c": -20, "b": 6, "p": "panther"}}}
```

If your real input does have scalars that start with special characters it might be easier to re-add them for these special cases than try to not remove them in the first place.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Anthon.. But facing issue if my string input is

dit = "'{p_d: '{a:3, what:3.6864e-05, s:lion, vec_md:'{2.5, -2.9, 3.4, 5.6, -8.9, -5.67, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5.4, 2, 2, 6.545, 2, 2}, sst:'{c:-20, b:6, p:panther}}}"

Comment: @Vimo I have no idea what you are trying to say. Do you mean did not give a representative example in your question? Or used a simple example instead of the most complex (for which the simple solution doesn't work)? `dit =` (if not Dutch and part of your comment sentence) is invalid YAML. IMO you should post a different question which allows proper formatting and provide  **representative** input and describe what errors you are facing, and not abuse comments to try and get interactive debugging help.

Comment: Hello @Anthon. Thanks for your help. Actually was trying different scenarios with the solution. Case 1 worked fine, but when tried different scenarios it failed. Wasn't abusing the comment section and was mainly trying with different cases to check full functionality. As suggested have updated the case and thanks again for your help.

Comment: What follows vec_mode seems more like a sequence/list. Because of the curly braces a YAML parser will see that as a mapping without values, and with duplicate keys, not allowed in YAML. You could try to convert that into a list (using `[` and `]`, but depending on the nesting, that might be nasty. Setting allow_duplicate_keys is definately not the right way forward.